# requestApplicationPermission userDiscoverability failed in Mac Catalyst

Tags: cloudkit, catalyst

I have ios app using requestApplicationPermission userDiscoverability. Today, I add Mac Catalyst support, but failed: "requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) failed, error: CloudKit access was denied by user settings".

```
container.requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { [weak self] (status, error) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
            foolPrint("requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) failed, error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I cannot find settings about userDiscoverability in mac settings, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [iCloud user guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/prevent-apps-from-showing-your-name-mmbffe88bb42/icloud) shows how to change these settings:

> 1. On iCloud.com, go to Account Settings, then click Manage Apps That Can Look You Up in the Advanced section.
> 2. To prevent an app from showing your name and email address to other users, deselect the app’s checkbox in the list.

[image: screenshot showing how to find the look me up by email setting]